# List of New Jersey businesses sorted by zip code and SIC code

Tags: data-request, business

I'm looking for a list of New Jersey businesses sorted by zip code and [SIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Industrial_Classification) code.

Comment: Have you tried visiting New Jersey's official government state site? Businesses usually have to register with the state government to pay taxes, and the state's records would include address (including zip code) and SIC code.

Comment: **In what format**??

Answer (score 2):

A potentially useful link to the State of NJ's page on public information related to business: http://www.nj.gov/treasury/revenue/guiderequest.shtml

Don't think there's anything that is directly downloadable/scrapable, but they may have data that you could request in a format you may want.